# Filter by tag in Activity - all actions - comments tab on User page

Tags: discussion, feature-request

On a user page, in *Activity - all actions - comments* tab (and maybe some others too, like *posts*), can we filter by tags please.

It would help a lot to find a discussion in a specific tag from few days ago, when I had a lot of activity in other tags since then.

Similarly, in *Activity - responses*.

Comment: Are you asking for something like this: user:849891 [discussion]  ?

Comment: @BSMP no, I want  to see my *comments*, and *responses* to me, for a certain tag.